# WebRTC on a standalone mobile app

Tags: webrtc

I know that `WebRTC` was designed for browsers, but is it possible to use WebRTC libraries on mobile applications directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Tokbox has some iOS libraries that integrate with webRTC.  Might be worth taking a look at ... http://www.tokbox.com/learn-about-webrtc

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this solution!

Comment: OpenTok isn't actually open source, and only works with their API.

Comment: Although many libraries address this now , my team made a native webrtc compatible android client 1 year back using SIP to WebRTC signalling and media gateway . Refer to article - https://altanaitelecom.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/webrtc-compatible-android-client/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of May 14 [here](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC) is an android project using `WebRTC` that works nicely.

I translated that entire android project to `Objective-C` for iOS and got WebRTC working in iOS too but I'm having trouble on iPhone 4 and 4s. Just works in iPhone 5 and 5s.

I think the problem is the performance. When I make a videocall with the webrtc libraries it takes about 140% of the CPU on an iPhone 5, which I guess that's a lot of resources and the iPhone 4s can't handle it.

---

Edited

After struggling with the video connection (always disconnected after 10 seconds) I finally got WebRTC working on iPhone 4s, all you have to do is set the right constraints when creating the local videoSource capturing object:

```
NSString *_width = @"320";
NSString *_height = @"180";
NSString *_maxFrameRate = @"10";

RTCMediaConstraints *videoConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]   
initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:_height],
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:_width],
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:_maxFrameRate]] optionalConstraints:@[[[RTCPair alloc] 
initWithKey:@"googCpuOveruseDetection" value:@"true"],
[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"googCpuLimitedResolution" value:@"true"]]];


RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:videoConstraints];
RTCMediaStream *lms = [factory mediaStreamWithLabel:@"ARDAMS"];
[lms addVideoTrack:[factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource]];
```

Note that this sends a very small video, but it works!

Comment: Olmedo, I am also porting AndroidRTC over to iOS. I seem to have succeeded in setting up init, offer, answer, ice flows. However, I cant seem to connect the video track to the video view. Is there something that I may be missing? Looking for help.. Thanks!

Comment: That's in my private repo. Can you drop me a handshake email at m.azfar.siddiqui@gmail.com so that I can coordinate with you further? Thanks

Comment: @MoisésOlmedo is there a way we can look to your source code?

Comment: @MoisésOlmedo Nice work... I am able to call from browser to Android client. can you please share the sample to call from Android to Android client...

Answer (score 12):

You could use WebRTC with native apps, but it requires a bit of work. 
[image: WebRTC Native app anatomy]

If you look at the image you can see a red rectangle at the bottom. That's the native C++ libraries of WebRTC. The WebRTC classes and WebRTC objects for audio and Video can also be found as part of the WebRTC project.What you would need to add is an API for your app to be able to setup calls(The VOIP interface), a signaling stack and NAT traversal utilities(Core Protocol- For SIP this could be something like PJSIP and PJNATH) and an adapter from your signaling stack to webrtc, telling it when to open channels for video and audio and when to stop them etc.

See also: http://bloggeek.me/porting-webrtc-mobile/

Answer (score 9):

As of today, WebRTC officially is available natively on Android/iOS.

https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/android/

https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/

Although under the hood, it is just a Java/Objective C wrapper around the C++ APIs.

You can still use them without going through JavaScript.

The Java wrapper API : https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/#talk%2Fapp%2Fwebrtc%2Fjava%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fwebrtc

The Objective C wrapper API :
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/#talk%2Fapp%2Fwebrtc%2Fobjc%2Fpublic%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid) is a sample project based on the WebRTC code and prebuilt libraries.

Answer (score 6):

We (disclaimer: I work there) have built a set of libraries for doing this @ Frozen Mountain, in [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink). Full WebRTC implementation for iOS, Android, .NET, etc.

Comment: Is there a cordova-version for iOS and Android?

Answer (score 5):

Let me summarize the answer, on Android Firefox actually has WebRTC support I believe, on the other hand there is a bunch of companies out there providing the full stack for building an WebRTC Product. If you are 
after just WebRTC and building the other stuff (addressing etc) your self you probably have to Build a couple of wrappers yourself.
(Disclaimer I work for sinch)

```
[http://sinch.com]
[http://twilio.com]
[http://tokbox.com]
[http://nexmo.com]
[http://plivo.com] (I think)
```

There is some more out there, but these are the main ones

We all have our different benefits and weaknesses. if you are interested send an email and I can talk about sinch.

Comment: hi @cjensen i tried to register users for video call using username on two different devices from same username. Somehow it is calling on first device how to make it available for only latest registered user. I know we can user stopClient method but in my conditions i can't use it. Please help me out of this

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to work with WebRTC in mobile applications with the use of 3rd-party API's like OpenTok (iOS only, as of January 2014 Android in beta) http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/downloads/index.html and Addlive (iOS and Android) http://www.addlive.com/platform-overview/

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2014, [here](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) is a way to do that, indeed:

That would be if you're interested in having a native client. If you don't mind using a mobile browser, the following ones are currently supported:

- Google Chrome 28 (Enabled by default since 29)
- Mozilla Firefox 24
- Opera Mobile 12

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC#Support):

Answer (score 3):

SightCall has a WebRTC-compatible SDK for Android that lets Android-native apps connect to WebRTC in a browser.
You can get the SDK [here](https://github.com/sightcall/Android-SDK)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what do you mean by "use WebRTC libraries on mobile applications directly".
But there is something that I'm already done.
Build WebRTC NS/AEC/AECM/AGC/VAD modules with JNI + NDK, and use the shared library on android.
or you can build whole WebRTC VoE and ViE for both android and iOS.

Comment: @bikkhoo : You mean, were you able to use webrtc on Android with Native App

Comment: @Amitg2k12 yep, NS/VAD modules works fine in my app, but AECM has a little trouble with screams.

Comment: thanks a lot it would be great if you can comment on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933532/using-webrtc-in-native-app

Answer (score 2):

One resource you might want to look at is this article:
[how to get started with webrtc and ios without wasting 10 hours of your life](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/)

One problem I am having is making sense of all the `WebRTC/Libjingle` library files. At the moment, I can get the example app running but I wish there was a "Hello World" example out there.

Comment: There is a **ApprtcDemo** project

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, it is only supported in Firefox's nightly and Chrome, both desktop versions. See http://www.webrtc.org

Edit: sorry I thought you were asking for mobile browsers. For native apps it looks like a definite no :(

But there seems some mobile browser support http://www.morbo.org/2013/04/webrtc-support-on-android.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But WebRTC project contains a lot of libraries written in C, so I suppose, it's needed to write an API for them. Still I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: WebRTC may theoretically be used in native mobile apps but the fact that it can be done doesn't mean that you can use it now. All those libraries should be ported to mobile OSes and for Android for example a Java interface(api) should be written by Android developers. So as regular users of mobile SDKs I guess we have to wait until those happen.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. I think it's all that I need to hear:)

Comment: actualy WebRTC used in mobile apps. Consider very popular Viber application - it is based on WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

For now you have two options:

- Either you will build libWebRTC for your device. You need to know how to work with Android NDK and native C code on iOS. It is non trivial but it's perfectly doable
- Use work of others who did this for you. E.g. already mentioned AddLive (yip, I work there) or even OpenTok.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, just add this to your CocoaPods Podfile

```
pod "libjingle_peerconnection"


# Add this to the bottom so it won't have issues with active architecture
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = ['armv7', 'i386']
        end
    end
end
```

Check [this](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/libjingle_peerconnection/6802.0/) for which revisions are available. Revision 6802.X reflects to [this](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/detail?r=6802) from the actual `WebRTC` code base.

Android will be added to maven central very soon, I'll make an edit to this when happens.

If you want to manually build WebRTC check out github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts which also includes a step by step guide for both platforms

Answer (score 0):

My team has done quite a bit of work in this area. If you are looking for a Cordova plugin we've been playing with an open source project called [PhoneRTC](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc). We have it running on iOS but it's a bit unreliable and the aspect ratio of the video window is fixed in a way that looks unnatural on most devices but it does work.

We've also created an Android demo using libjingle. Libjingle is now part of the WebRTC project and code base. [This](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/) link is probably out of date now but points to instructions that worked for us at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to answer..
But i just made a framework for adding WebRTC easily in iOS Project.
You won't need to build WebRTC framework from the library.
This framework will give you built in framework along with a wrapper for easy addition of webRTC to your app.
https://github.com/Ankit-Aggarwal/SwiftyWebRTC

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting android >= L you can build a native webRTC app pretty easily by embedding a (chrome) webview - which supports WebRTC - into your app.

See [chrome webview](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)