# WebRTC on Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I would like to use WebRTC on Titanium. In the end of last year, WebRTC was implemented on Chrome for Android. I would like to make an application with WebRTC on Android.

I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to use WebRTC on native webview or it is only for chrome?
2. What is the simplest way to implement webRTC on Android?

I have found the old article about webRTC on mobile here [WebRTC on a standalone mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517935/webrtc-on-a-standalone-mobile-app/19519395#19519395) but it is old, how has the situation changed now?

Comment: WebRTC was just enabled in Chromium webview.
 http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=revision&revision=253110

Comment: As of today, the simplest way is to add the official implementation as dependency to your project - implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'. Check out this [Android Studio project](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid) on GitHub.

Comment: You can follow this article to Kick Start your webrtc android journey:

[Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC.git)

Answer (score 11):

*Just an update on WebRTC for those seeing this post later:*

### WebRTC Library

If you are only catering to Android L (5.0), you can use the [updated WebView](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#WebView). I am not sure you can support older Android versions with a WebView though. You can take the native option of course.

As other users mentioned, compiling WebRTC source files is certainly a viable option if you have the time and resources. However, if you would like to get up and running faster, [Pristine.io](http://tech.pristine.io/automated-webrtc-building/) is dedicated to hosting up to date WebRTC Android artifacts. To begin using WebRTC natively on your Android, you can add the following to your app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { 
   ... 
   compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar' 
}
```

At the time I am writing this, I have been working with WebRTC on Android for the past few months, and the most recent revision I have been using is 9694. Find the most recent revision [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.pristine/libjingle/9456).

### Getting Started on Android

As with WebRTC's javascript library, you will need a service to take care of user discovery and SDP signaling. I built a [WebRTC Signaling API](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-api) using [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) for the signaling service. You can include it and begin to use it right away by adding the following to your app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar'
    compile 'me.kevingleason:pnwebrtc:1.0.6@aar'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'    //optional
}
```

### Additional Resources

- [Signaling API Documentation](http://kevingleason.me/android-webrtc-api/)
- [Sample Android WebRTC App](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC)
- [Tutorial on making an Android WebRTC app with signaling library](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial)

Comment: I use 'io.pristine:libjingle:9694@aar'  ... my question is that there are many other versions after 9694 but they are just not compatible... am I loosing updates and bug fixes by using this version ?

Comment: Hi somehow I can not use this anymore `compile 'me.kevingleason:pnwebrtc:1.0.6@aar'` I get this error `Failed to resolve: pnwebrtc` I am using Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: pubnub is not free of cost its only free for 100 devices only..?

Comment: io.pristine:libjingle is old and not updated. it is better to use [api 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24277']  it is very active

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/), it is sample android application provided for apprtc demo of webrtc. Follow the instructions on this link, you will get android application which you can test on two android devices, also on android to web apprtc demo works fine. Following the source code you may get some clue for developing your own android application for android.

Note:The link provided in this example for gclient config command is older one. Follow this link

**gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk**

Good luck.

Comment: project doesnt build properly using the guide

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible in Android using crosswalk. Please refer to this  https://crosswalk-project.org/