# How to WebRTC on android

Tags: android, webrtc

I recently got a requirement to implement live video streaming from mobile(android) to web. I googled and cane across WebRTC. It looked promising as it was an initiative by google. I went through some of its videos but they kept talking about web browser and chrome. They said its supported on android but could not find any resource in that direction. So how can I implement WebRTC from Android ? Can someone direct me to some demo or tutorial on implementing WebRTC on Android devices ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085239/webrtc-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is an app for Android, then take the code from webrtc.org, compile and use it as your own inside your application.

You can check out this video for some more details

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS1eKPL4f1o&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIDIdBEM7KUPty_tDX1xnrYm&index=3

Comment: Now easier way is to add dependency (implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'). Check out [this project](https://github.com/duttaime/webrtcandroid).